# Нужно в Android-приложение интегрировать подсказки сервиса DaData.ru

Tags: android, запрос, сервисы

Всем привет. Нужно, чтобы в приложении, после ввода ИНН предприятия, подгружались все остальные данные из ЕГРЮЛ. Решено пользоваться сервисом DaData.ru.

На сайте сервиса уже есть пример интеграции-размещения на android подсказок для автозаполнения почтового адреса. Он хорошо работает, но для меня не подходит. Хотел было переделать, раз думаю каркас есть, запрос переделаю и дальше поеду. Заглянул внутрь... понял, что переделывать я буду очень долго (написано программером 80-го уровня, слишком мудрёно для меня).

Вопрос. В моем случае код обязательно будет таким мудрёным как [здесь](https://github.com/zsavely/DaDataExample)? Или это просто маньяк писал, и можно всё проще сделать?

Comment: Вашим ответом удовлетворён - упрощать некуда, так всё и должно быть, значит буду разбираться. Rostislav Dugin, ответьте пожалуйста "Ответом".

Comment: @RostislavDugin да далеко не самый лучший код для задач обучения. Один адский синглтон чего стоит... Да и старый довольно, аж с первым ретрофитом

Comment: @rjhdby, старый - это уже простите человека, ничего с этим не поделать. А синглтон не всегда плохое решение, иногда без него совсем никак не обойтись (не в конкретном примере, а вообще).

Comment: @RostislavDugin я не про факт наличия, а про его реализацию. Хотя, конечно, это холиварный вопрос.

Comment: @rjhdby  Этот код оказался пока лучшим для задач самообучения. Уйма нового. Бессонные ночи в режиме напряженного гуглпарсинга позволяют и "слона" потихоньку "съесть".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Код в программе хороший, при чем с документацией и комментариями. Если для Вас это сложно - не стоит сейчас за него браться, повысьте свой уровень знаний.

P.S. К тому же, как заметили в комментариях, код старый и его улучшение довольно трудоемкая задача, особенно для неподготовленного человека.